# The character '+' is converted into &#x2B; in base64 encoded data

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I'm trying to append image retrieved from database into nodes in my force directed graph in D3.js as shown below:

```
var node = container.append("g").attr("class", "nodes")
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter()
            .append("image")
            .attr("xlink:href", "data:image/jpeg;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(photo)")
            .attr("x", -8)
            .attr("y", -8)
            .attr("width", 30)
            .attr("height", 30);
```

However, I discover that the character `+` is encoded as `&#x2B;` causing error 'invalid URL'.

Correct encoded string: `...3V1a+Z7p4m...`
After passing to function: `...3V1a&#x2B;Z7p4m...`

Can anyone provide a solution to this?

Comment: have you tried `@Html.Raw(...)`

Comment: Daniel A. White omg thanks, this solves the problem!

Answer (score 14):

Razor is doing some encoding. You will have to change it to use `@Html.Raw` to skip the encoding.